# Controller unable to retrieve record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My controller is searching for a record without the user_id I am passing to it.

This is my controller:

```
def update
@untrained = Certificate.find_by_user_id(params[:id])
@untrained.update_attributes(attend: "No")
redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path
end
```

This is the error:

```
Processing by CertificatesController#update as 
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx=", "certificate"=>{"user_id"=>"7"}, "commit"=>"Un-Train"}
```

> Certificate Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `certificates`.* FROM `certificates` WHERE `certificates`.`user_id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

The user_id is being sent as a string, the user_id in Certificate is a integer. 
Why is my SELECT searching with a user_id as NULL?

Comment: The `find_by_*` magic methods are deprecated. Use `Certificate.where(user_id: params[:id])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the `"certificate"=>{"user_id"=>"7"},` in your log.

You  need `params[:certificate][:user_id]`, not `params[:id]`.

```
Certificate.where(user_id: params[:id]).first.update_attributes(attend: "No")
```

Comment: Not sure if this is related, I get this error: NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attributes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000005001720>):

Comment: If you want to use `where` instead of `find_by`, you need to add a `first` to turn the *set* of records into a *specific* record. See update.